# How to get rid of com.teaksoftware.veStartAtLogin (Mac OSX 10.9.5, MacBook Pro, late 2011)

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, console

I am on a MacBook Pro, late 2011 model, running OSX 10.9.5).

Looking at the system log, I get about every 10 seconds the following entries:

```
Jan 29 18:48:44 mymachine com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[345] (com.teaksoftware.veStartAtLogin[5852]): Exited with code: 1
Jan 29 18:48:44 mymachine com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[345] (com.teaksoftware.veStartAtLogin): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Process 345 is launchd.

This looks like it has something to do with Vecte by Teaksoftware.

I had this program installed, but in the meantime, I have completely removed it (including the .plists in the LaunchAgents folders). Doing a find for *ecte* gives no more files related to Vecte, except in backups and the Trash. I also restarted the machine. Therefore, there should no longer be any references to anything from teaksoftware.

Am I missing something?

How can I get rid of this?

Thanks a lot in advance for any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w -D all com.teaksoftware.veStartAtLogin
```

If that doesn't get it, there are a handful of locations that startup programs and plists can be stored on OS X. Make sure you check all of them

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/StartupItems
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/StartupItems
```

And of course System Preferences > Users & Groups > Select Your User > Login Items

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the time you took for it. The problem solved itself insofar, as the system disk gave up its ghost last night, and after restoring from the TimeMachine, the effect no longer exists…